# Animations for a Rubik's cube

Tags: java, animation, 3d, javafx-8

I came up with a model of a 2x2 Rubik's cube built using `TriangleMesh` and transforming them by using different transformations. Now I want to add animations to the cube. I don't know a good algorithm for this, but tried something myself. I made four `Group` objects and added the cubes which made the front, back, left and right faces of it. I also used an array of type `Node` to store all cubes in a sequential manner so as to keep track of the cubes which would represent the front, back, left and right faces with each movement of the cube.
[Here's a snapshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3fKh.png)
The front and the back faces are rotating fine, if done without making the left and right faces. Once I move the left face the cubes overlap. What mistake am I making? Is there a better way to perform the animations ?
This is the animation part of the program.

```
//ADDING ANIMATIONS TO THE CUBE
        Button F = new Button("F");
        Button F_ = new Button("F_");
        Button B = new Button("B");
        Button B_ = new Button("B_");
        Button L = new Button("L");
        Button L_ = new Button("L_");
        Button R = new Button("R");
        Button R_ = new Button("R_");
        Button X = new Button("X");
        Button X_ = new Button("X_");
        Button Y = new Button("Y");
        Button Y_ = new Button("Y_");
        Button Z = new Button("Z");
        Button Z_ = new Button("Z_");

        Group front=new Group(c1,c2,c5,c6);
        Group back=new Group(c3,c4,c7,c8);
        Group right=new Group(c1,c4,c5,c8);
        Group left=new Group(c2,c3,c6,c7);


        PerspectiveCamera camera2 = new PerspectiveCamera(true);



        //moves- normal letters represent clockwise and underscored ones represent anticlockwise rotations.
        F.setTranslateY(200);
        F_.setTranslateY(170);
        B.setTranslateY(140);
        B_.setTranslateY(110);
        L.setTranslateY(80);
        L_.setTranslateY(50);
        R.setTranslateY(20);
        R_.setTranslateY(-10);

        X.setTranslateY(-40);
        X_.setTranslateY(-70);
        Y.setTranslateY(-100);
        Y_.setTranslateY(-130);
        Z.setTranslateY(-160);
        Z_.setTranslateY(-190);

        Node ar[]={/*front*/c1,c5,c6,c2,/*back*/c4,c8,c7,c3,/*right*/c1,c5,c8,c4,/*left*/c2,c6,c7,c3}; 

                                          //Groups of rectangles with each 4 of them taken together in sequence represent the  
                                          //initial front, back, right, and left faces respectively. The array is to updated with each 
                                          //movement of the cube to represent the faces correctly.    
        Node ar_prev[]={/*front*/c1,c5,c6,c2,/*back*/c4,c8,c7,c3,/*right*/c1,c5,c8,c4,/*left*/c2,c6,c7,c3};
        Group r=new Group(F,F_,B,B_,L,L_,R,R_);
        Scene s=new Scene(r,600,600,true);
        camera2.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera2.setFarClip(10000.0);


        F.setOnAction(e -> {
            front.getChildren().removeAll(ar_prev[0],ar_prev[1],ar_prev[2],ar_prev[3]);
            front.getChildren().addAll(ar[0],ar[1],ar[2],ar[3]);
            int ctr=0;
            for(Node i:ar)
            {
                ar_prev[ctr++]=i;
            }
            front.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), front);
            rt.setByAngle(90);
            rt.play();
            Node temp=ar[3];

            ar[3]=ar[2];
            ar[12]=ar[2];//for left
            ar[2]=ar[1];
            ar[13]=ar[1];//for left
            ar[1]=ar[0];
            ar[9]=ar[0];//for right
            ar[0]=temp;
            ar[8]=temp;//for right

                });

        F_.setOnAction(e -> {
            front.getChildren().removeAll(ar_prev[0],ar_prev[1],ar_prev[2],ar_prev[3]);
            front.getChildren().addAll(ar[0],ar[1],ar[2],ar[3]);
            int ctr=0;
            for(Node i:ar)
            {
                ar_prev[ctr++]=i;
            }
            front.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), front);
            rt.setByAngle(-90);
            rt.play();
            Node temp=ar[0];
            ar[0]=ar[1];
            ar[8]=ar[1];//right
            ar[1]=ar[2];
            ar[9]=ar[2];//right
            ar[2]=ar[3];
            ar[13]=ar[3];//left
            ar[3]=temp;
            ar[12]=temp;//left

                });
        root.getChildren().addAll(front);
        B.setOnAction(e -> {
            back.getChildren().removeAll(ar_prev[4],ar_prev[5],ar_prev[6],ar_prev[7]);
            back.getChildren().addAll(ar[4],ar[5],ar[6],ar[7]);
            int ctr=0;
            for(Node i:ar)
            {
                ar_prev[ctr++]=i;
            }
            back.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), back);
            rt.setByAngle(90);
            rt.play();
            Node temp=ar[7];

            ar[7]=ar[6];
            ar[15]=ar[6];//for left
            ar[6]=ar[5];
            ar[14]=ar[5];//for left
            ar[5]=ar[4];
            ar[10]=ar[4];//for right
            ar[4]=temp;
            ar[11]=temp;//for right
                });

        B_.setOnAction(e -> {
            back.getChildren().removeAll(ar_prev[4],ar_prev[5],ar_prev[6],ar_prev[7]);
            back.getChildren().addAll(ar[4],ar[5],ar[6],ar[7]);
            int ctr=0;
            for(Node i:ar)
            {
                ar_prev[ctr++]=i;
            }
            back.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), back);
            System.out.println("hhhh");
            rt.setByAngle(-90);
            rt.play();
            Node temp=ar[4];
            ar[4]=ar[5];
            ar[11]=ar[5];//right
            ar[5]=ar[6];
            ar[10]=ar[6];//right
            ar[6]=ar[7];
            ar[14]=ar[7];//left
            ar[7]=temp;
            ar[15]=temp;//left
                });
        root.getChildren().addAll(back);


        L.setOnAction(e -> {
            left.getChildren().removeAll(ar_prev[12],ar_prev[13],ar_prev[14],ar_prev[15]);
            left.getChildren().addAll(ar[12],ar[13],ar[14],ar[15]);
            int ctr=0;
            for(Node i:ar)
            {
                ar_prev[ctr++]=i;
            }
            left.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), left);
            rt.setByAngle(90);
            rt.play();
            Node temp=ar[15];

            ar[15]=ar[14];
            ar[7]=ar[14];//for back
            ar[14]=ar[13];
            ar[6]=ar[13];//for back
            ar[13]=ar[12];
            ar[2]=ar[12];//for front
            ar[12]=temp;
            ar[3]=temp;//for front
                });

        L_.setOnAction(e -> {

            left.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), left);
            rt.setByAngle(-90);
            rt.play();
                });
        root.getChildren().addAll(left);


        R.setOnAction(e -> {
            right.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), right);
            rt.setByAngle(90);
            rt.play();
                });

        R_.setOnAction(e -> {
            right.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
            RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(2000), right);
            rt.setByAngle(-90);
            rt.play();
                });
        root.getChildren().addAll(right);
        camera2.getTransforms().addAll (new Translate(0, 0, -1000));
        s.setCamera(camera2);
        r.getChildren().addAll(scene);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve proper animations of the cube, because for ta 3x3 cube this will be very long?

Comment: I think I figured out what is the problem. I am applying transformations to the nodes as a group but not to the nodes individually. The transformations are not applied to the nodes individually but only to the group. That's why even if I am updating my `back`,`front`, `left` groups all the nodes still get the starting position and not the new position. Can anyone please suggest me how to fix this up ?